# QuickCheck limit to only certain data constructor

Tags: haskell

I have a data type definition:

```
data Point = Point {x :: Int, h :: Int} | EmptyPoint
```

In my property test, I would like to limit the test only on the Point constructor cases. For example point1 - point2 = Point 0 0. This presumes that the accessor `x` is defined which is not the case with EmptyPoint.

in other words: I don't want EmptyPoint to be generated.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if your problem is the fact that you want to restrict the generation of objects, *or* if you want to add a "getter" `x` to `EmptyPoint`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I suppose quickcheck generates random data for type Point. What I want is that it does not generate EmptyPoint

Comment: Well you need to make `Point` an instance of `Arbitrary`. So that means that you can specify how to generate arbitrary `Point`s exactly how you want that to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of automatically deriving the `Arbitrary` class for your type (which is what, I assume, you're doing at the moment), you can just write one manually and make it generate your points however you want, for example:

```
instance Arbitrary Point where
    arbitrary = Point <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary
```

Or in a slightly more verbose way if you like:

```
instance Arbitrary Point where
    arbitrary = do
        x <- arbitrary
        y <- arbitrary
        pure Point { x, y }
```